# When click the element which will be toggled , toggles itself

Tags: jquery, toggle

Guys when click the element which will be toggled element, it toggles itself.Why? Just dont get , maybe making a typo or forgot something, i do not know.Just  made headache.
Thanks for your help!
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/87j3g40z/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dropdown').hide();
  $('#list li:nth-child(4) a').click(function() {
    $('#dropdown').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fixed-side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#list li a {
  position: Relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: Center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

#list li a:hover {
  background: #367a8b;
}

#dropdown {
  background: #367a8b;
  display:Block;
}

#dropdown li a {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed-side-menu">
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's because, the buttons inside the dropdown are also matching `#list li:nth-child(4) a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select only anchors which are direct child of specific `li` element (btw, you should select only `li:nth-child(4)` which is direct child of `#list`):

```
$('#list > li:nth-child(4) > a').click(function() {
    $('#dropdown').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Otherwise, you were including anchor in `#dropdown` too.

### -jsFiddle-